# How to implement drag and drop (drag to reorder) with CodeceptJs

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, webdriver, codeceptjs

I have this request to implement drag and drop between two cards so they swap their positions, so more specifically a "drag to reorder". Not sure how to tackle this scenario considering the container would not be empty when I’m dropping the new item into it? I see examples for Selenium and Protractor but can't find ones for CodeceptJs.

I tried this here

```
await I.dragAndDrop('//*[@id="myAssessments"]/main/div/div[7]/div[2]/div[1]/li', '//*[@id="myAssessments"]/main/div/div[7]/div[2]',);
```

which I believe to be the equivalent to

```
I.dragAndDrop('#dragHandle', '#container');
```

from https://codecept.io/helpers/WebDriver/#draganddrop using the xpath for the container and the one for the first list item but the element did not drag and I got the error `Element "{null: undefined}" was not found by text|CSS|XPath`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got it working now. We needed to use a **custom function**.

It seems as perhaps due to the fact that our **elements have rounded corners, the 0,0 position is not being reached**, so we need to try to get the middle for the element.

Therefore, this is what we needed to do.

```
await I.dragDown(
  {
    css:
      '#myAssessments > main > div > * > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)',
  },
  200,
); 

async dragDown(locator, pixels) {
  await this.dragInDirection('down', locator, pixels);
}

async dragInDirection(direction, locator, pixels) {
  const queryString = resolveLocator(locator);
  const location = await this.getElementLocation(queryString);
  const x = parseInt(location.x + location.width / 2, 10);
  const y = parseInt(location.y + location.height / 2, 10);
  await this.performBrowserActions([
    createActionSet({ x, y }, direction, pixels),
  ]);
}

function resolveLocator(locator) {
  let queryString;
  if (locator.dataTestId) {
    queryString = `[data-testid=${locator.dataTestId}]`;
  } else if (locator.test) {
    queryString = `[data-test-id=${locator.test}]`;
  } else if (locator.css) {
    queryString = locator.css;
  } else {
    queryString = locator;
  }
  return queryString;
}

function createActionSet(origin, direction, length) {
 const { x, y } = origin;

 let xMoveTo = 0;
 let yMoveTo = 0;

 switch (direction) {
    case 'up':
      yMoveTo = -length;
      break;
    case 'down':
      yMoveTo = length;
      break;
    case 'right':
      xMoveTo = length;
      break;
    case 'left':
      xMoveTo = -length;
      break;
    default:
      return new Error('Direction passed was wrong or no direction passed');
  }

return {
    type: 'pointer',
    id: 'finger1',
    parameters: { pointerType: 'touch' },
    actions: [
      { type: 'pointerMove', duration: 0, x, y },
      { type: 'pointerDown', button: 0 },
      { type: 'pause', duration: 500 },
      {
        type: 'pointerMove',
        duration: 1000,
        origin: 'pointer',
        x: xMoveTo,
        y: yMoveTo,
      },
      { type: 'pointerUp', button: 0 },
    ],
  };
}
```

If not using custom locators you can perhaps simplify and do it like this:

```
async dragInDirection(direction, locator, pixels) {
  const location = await this.getElementLocation(locator);
  const x = parseInt(location.x + location.width / 2, 10);
  const y = parseInt(location.y + location.height / 2, 10);
  await this.performBrowserActions([
    createActionSet({ x, y }, direction, pixels),
  ]);
}
```

**And here is the version with keyboard tabbing:**

```
await I.pressKey('Tab');
await I.pressKey('Tab'); // Tabbing to focus the card
await I.pressKey('Space'); // "Jump" item
await I.pressKey('ArrowDown'); // Move item
await I.pressKey('Space'); // Drop item
```